# Подскажите, с помощью чего реализовать функционал в 1С Битрикс УС

Tags: битрикс

Подскажите новичку.
Необходимо на сайте битрикса сделать возможность, что бы зарегистрированные посетители на сайте могли писать свои новости\посты, которые в свою очередь появлялись бы на сайте после прохождения модерации.
Выглядеть это вообщем должно так, как список новостей в итоге, с указанием автора, ссылкой на его профиль.
И за каждый пост, который пройдет модерацию, пользователю автоматически начислялись баллы, в зависимости от количества символов в посте и наличия загруженного фото (превью)
В дальнейшем эти баллы можно тратить на покупки в интернет-магазине на этом же сайте (оплатить баллами часть стоимости)

Может быть есть какие то компоненты\модули готовые, путсь даже и платные, или шаблоны\темы, которые под это уже заточены?

Знаю, что есть стандартный компонент "Блоги", но там много лишнего функционала и в изначальном варианте он крайне не привлекательный